# Project Management from customer service to development

Tags: version-control, project-management, issue-tracking

which project management solutions do you know, which fullfill the following contraints:

- Report customer issue
- Create development tasks assiciated with the issue
- Associate development and q/a documents to the tasks
- Create a patch/revision which contains the development result
- Associate patch/revision with customer issue

Another problem we face is that each customer has a slightly different code base. And not all customers want to have all features/fixes.

Are there Open Source / Commercial project management solutions, which would fit those requirements?

Regards,

Martin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Open Source Ticketsystem called Trac, in connection with SVN you can connect Tickets with revisions, create a own ticketsystem for each customer, and so on (:

Its running on a Apache Server, and its looking like the Homepage

Link: http://trac.edgewall.org/

Alex

Comment: Thanks Alex, that sounds promising. I'll have a look.